# application crashing however logcat shows no Caused by:

Tags: java, android

My application is crashing while submitting on the register page but logcat is not showing a Caused by (I think it might be my php server app that is making it all crash but im unsure)

If there is any code you would link me to show you all to help with this issue please comment and I will try and help.

```
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at com.loggedin.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:173)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at com.loggedin.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-24 10:36:43.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8764):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Login page code

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.loggedin.internal.DatabaseHandler; 
import com.loggedin.internal.UserFunctions;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class Login extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button registerbtn1;
Button passwordresetbtn;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputPassword;
private TextView loginErrorMsg;
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
 private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
 private static String KEY_UID = "id";
 private static String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
 private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
 private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "LastName";
 private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
 private static String KEY_DOB = "DOB";
 private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    registerbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn1);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn1);
    passwordresetbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passwordresetbtn);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
    passwordresetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordReset.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    finish();
    }});
    registerbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
         }});
 /**
 * Login button click event
 * A Toast is set to alert when the Email and Password field is empty
  **/
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
     if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && (   !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                InternetAsync(view);
            }
            else if ( ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "USername field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Username and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
 }
 /**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
 **/
 private class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask <String, String, Boolean>    {
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){
   /**
   * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
   **/
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessLogin().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
  }
 /**
 * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
 **/
  private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask <String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String Username, Password;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        Username = inputUsername.getText().toString();
        Password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(Username, Password);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
           if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    /**
                     * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                     **/
                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                     db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_DOB),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID));
                   /**
                    *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                    **/
                    Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                    upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(upanel);
                    /**
                     * Close Login Screen
                     **/
                    finish();
                }else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
 }
```

Comment: post code around this error or you will be downvoted

Comment: Login.java -line number 173 - NullPointerException. Look at that line.

Comment: Sorry nikis, I was unsure where the error was coming from and I didnt want to paste in all of my code.    Thank you Dmitry I will look there now

Comment: '_I was unsure where the error was coming from_'; This can't be right, because the first thing you see when you look at your Logcat is: `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.loggedin.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:173)`

Answer (score 0):

Verify if any variable is null in onPostExecute method on `onPostExecute`